# Why line break is not working in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using `\n` to put a header in each line, but its not working, always prints the `\n`.

code:

```
const getHeaders = (config) => {
  const rawHeaders = getRawHeaders(config)

  let headers = ''

  for (const rawHeader in rawHeaders) {
    headers += ` -H ${rawHeader}: ${rawHeaders[rawHeader]} \n`
  }
  
  return headers
}
```

terminal:

```
 "request": "  -H name: john \n -H city: London \n ",
```

Comment: The problem here will be what you *do* with the string, not JavaScript. (Side note: You seem to have an extra `'` in there. May not relate to your question, but it seems odd.)

Comment: What do you mean by "its not working"? The terminal shows the new line character is in the string. What do you want it to be instead?

Comment: you don't need to add \n when you are using back-quotes. you can directly add a line break by pressing enter or remove the extra quote ( ' ) after \n

Comment: Where are you running this code. What *terminal* is this? Maybe that doesn't supposrt `\n`. It works fine in the browser's console

Comment: Im using vs code terminal.
i want to see like this:

(two expressions in two lines)
"request": "-H name: john"
"-H city: london"

Answer (score -1):

Below code will work

```js
const getHeaders = (config) => {
    const rawHeaders ={name:"John",city:"London"}
  
    let headers = ''
  
    for (const rawHeader in rawHeaders) {
      headers += `"-H ${rawHeader}: ${rawHeaders[rawHeader]}" \n`
    }
    
    return headers
  }
  console.log(getHeaders())
```